# How To Use MySql in Html Button with php

Tags: php, html, mysql

**PHP**

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mmogezgini");
$menuler = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menuler");
while($menu = mysqli_fetch_array($menuler))
{
    echo "<button class=\"ust_link\"
        onClick=\"window.location.href='Menu_Url.php'\">Menu_Name</button>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

MySQL codes are ready and MySQL connection is successful, I just dont know how to place `menu['name']` and `menu['url']` instead of `Menu_Name` and `Menu_Url`

Comment: the simplest solution, what about declaring two strings and then concatenate whole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php
while($menu = mysqli_fetch_array($menuler)) {
   $name = $menu["Name'"];
   $url = $menu["url"];
?>
   <button class="ust_link" onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo $url; ?>'"><?php echo $name; ?></button>
<?php
 }
?>
```

It's gonna be difficult to echo out all of the html at once since you're using

```
onclick="location.href=''"
```

which combines single and double quotes

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilites :

```
echo "<button class=\"ust_link\" onClick=\"window.location.href='". $menu['url'].".php'\">". $menu['name'] ."</button>";
```

Or :

```
echo "<button class=\"ust_link\" onClick=\"window.location.href='{$menu['url']}'\">{$menu['name']}</button>";
```

See [PHP: echo - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Comment: it wont work i dont know why i copied exactly what you type it outputting text like this ". $menu['isim'] .""; } mysqli_close($con); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mmogezgini");
    $menuler = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menuler");
    while($menu = mysqli_fetch_array($menuler))
      {
      echo "<button class=\"ust_link\" onClick=\"window.location.href='".$menu['url'].".php'\">".menu['php']."</button>";
      }
    mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mmogezgini");
    $menuler = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menuler");
    while($menu = mysqli_fetch_array($menuler))
    {
        echo "<button class=\"ust_link\"onClick=\"window.location.href='".$menu['url'].".php'\">". $menu['name'] ."</button>";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
```